# Is there an informative term for calling the random elements conditional on which a PDF of a random element is defined?

Tags: references, density-function, terminology, conditioning

Let $X_{1}, \dots, X_{n}$ be i.i.d. random elements; suppose the conditional PDF $f_{X_{1} \mid X_{2} , \dots, X_{n}}$ exists. Then I wonder if there is already in literature an informative name for $X_{2}, \dots, X_{n}$ here? Thanks.